# BeautifulSoup cannot work in multithread program of Python

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup

When I try to parse html by BeautifulSoup in multithread, I find it can not work. For presenting the problem, two experiments are run. The first one is used to demonstrate the two subprograms are corrent, and the second shows one subprogram can run well, while another cannot.
I wonder why this happens, and how can I get deep into it.

Environment:

- Python 3.7
- bs4 installed

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def work_parser(ip):
    t = ip.find_all('td')
    time.sleep(5)
    print(t[1].text)

def work_print(ip):
    time.sleep(5)
    print(ip)

html = BeautifulSoup(r'<tr class="odd"><td class="country"><img alt="Cn" src="//fs.xicidaili.com/' \
       r'images/flag/cn.png"/></td><td>117.69.153.136</td><td>9999</td></tr>')
ips = html.find_all('tr', class_='odd')

time.sleep(1)

print('### Experiment 1')
print('This experiment presents that work_parser and work_print are correct')

print('---1.1 work_parser execute in order')
for ip in ips:
    work_parser(ip)

print('---1.2 work_print execute in order')
for ip in ips:
    work_print(ip)

print('\n')
print('### Experiment 2')
print('--- This experiment presents that in multithread running, work_print cuns well, but work_parser does not.')

print('---2.1 work_parser execute by thread')
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for ip in ips:
        executor.submit(work_parser, (ip,))

print('---2.2 work_print execute by thread')
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for ip in ips:
        executor.submit(work_print, (ip,))

print('--- Experiment is over')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are passing tuple of arguments to executor.submit() method in second place. Although it should get simple arguments. Changing (ip,) to simply (ip) will fix the problem.

```
print('---2.1 work_parser execute by thread')
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for ip in ips:
        executor.submit(work_parser, (ip))

print('---2.2 work_print execute by thread')
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for ip in ips:
        executor.submit(work_print, (ip))
```

Comment: Would you like to tell me how to debug the multiprocessing programming in Python.